# InstagramApiSharp. Proxy problems

Tags: c#, proxy

I'm using the InstagramApiSharp library.  I connect a proxy, no errors occur, but when I log into my account, Instagram sends an attempt to log in from my current location.  That is, proxies do not work.  Although they are workers.  I hope for your help.  I don't understand if there is a problem with the api or if I am doing something wrong.

```
 var userSession = new UserSessionData
        {
            UserName = username,
            Password = password
        };


        WebProxy wp = new WebProxy()
        {
            Address = new Uri($"http://ip:port"),
            BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(
userName: "username",
password: "password")
        };
        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = wp
          
            
        };

      

        var InstaApi = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
            .SetUser(userSession)
            .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions))
            .UseHttpClientHandler(httpClientHandler)
            .Build();


        //InstaApi.UseHttpClientHandler(GetHttpHandler());
        //InstaApi.HttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://i.instagram.com/");

        var result = await InstaApi.LoginAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out proxies below .Net Core 2.1 are not working.  Prior to .Net Core 2.1, the HttpClientHandler class used the old http protocols.